# dataSnapshot.getChildren() fetches userID but not the values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While running this code:

```
private void getData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Log.d(TAG, "UserID inside getData: "+userID);
        Log.d(TAG, "User Name inside getData: "+ds.child(userID).child("name").getValue());
        Log.d(TAG, "DS inside getData: "+ds.child(userID));

        hospitalCity = String.valueOf(ds.child(userID).child("city").getValue());
        Log.d(TAG, "User city inside getData: "+ds.child(userID).child("city").getValue());

        break;
    }
}
```

The log shows this:

> UserID inside getData: Lsncj8CIsfTQXc7E425AtLuDI5v2
>   User Name inside getData: null
>   DS inside getData: DataSnapshot { key = Lsncj8CIsfTQXc7E425AtLuDI5v2, value = null }
>
> D/DonorList: User city inside getData: null

Here's the database:

[image: title]]

So as you can see, it fetches the key but the value is `null` despite the database showing that it has values in it.

Comment: Could you update database image url ? If you have user class class, you should access your user object like ds.getValue(User.class) after that you can access properties of your objects

Comment: @gokhan i have updated the url. and I didn't use any user class

Comment: remove the for loop

Comment: @SouradipChakraborty "Lsncj8CIsfTQXc7E425AtLuDI5v2" key is root node of database ?

Comment: @gokhan No. The hierarchy is like this, "e-blood->Hospitals->Lsncj8CIsfTQXc7E425AtLuDI5v2" then the rest

Comment: we need to see the bigger picture, could you post the code that calls that function as well as the complete schema?

Comment: Please add you entire database structure and the code where you are calling `getData` method.

Comment: @AlexMamo
https://github.com/NeelChakraborty/E-Blood/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/e_blood/DonorList.java
This is the link to the code.

https://imgur.com/a/Zx52A
Link to the database structure.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque
https://github.com/NeelChakraborty/E-Blood/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/e_blood/DonorList.java
This is the link to the code.

https://imgur.com/a/Zx52A
Link to the database structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the data under the `Hospital` node, you need to change the following reference:

```
hospitalDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

with

```
hospitalDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital");
```

To get the data inside the `getData()` method, please use the following code:

```
private void getData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key = ds.getKey();
        String city = ds.child("city").getValue(String.class);
        String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
    }
}
```

`ds.getKey()` will return the userId

`ds.child("city").getValue(String.class)` will return the city.

`ds.child("name").getValue(String.class)` will return the name.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private void getData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Log.d(TAG, "UserID inside getData: "+userID);
        Log.d(TAG, "User Name inside getData: "+ds.child("name").getValue());
        Log.d(TAG, "DS inside getData: "+ds.child(userID));

        hospitalCity = String.valueOf(ds.child("city").getValue());
        Log.d(TAG, "User city inside getData: "+ds.child("city").getValue());

        break;
    }
}
```

`ds.getKey()` This should return the `userID`

What you are doing there is going one level deeper by using `.getChildren()`
If you are looking for only one value there is no need for `getChildren()`, just set your `ValueEventListener()` like for example:

```
    hospitalDatabase.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   hospitalCity = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

I think you are looking only for one value because of the `break` there.